# Error login script mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this login code:

```
$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $password = md5($_POST['password']);
 $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username=? AND   password=? LIMIT 1");
 $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
 $stmt->store_result();
 if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
 {
  $result=$con->query($stmt);
  $row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  $status = $row['status'];
  if($status=='d') {
   echo "YOUR account has been DEACTIVATED.";
  } else {
   $_SESSION['Logged'] = 1;
   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
   echo 'Success!';
   exit();
  }
 }
 else {
  echo "INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD Combination!";
 }
 $stmt->close();
}
else 
{   
}
$con->close();
```

and when press login buton is show me this errors:

```
Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /nginx/html/user/demo/login.php on line 93    
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object in /nginx/html/user/demo/login.php on line 94
```

There is lines with this errors:

line 93 is:  $result=$con->query($stmt); 
line 94 is   $row=$result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you're using prepared statements, you don't call `query` or `fetch_array`. You call `fetch`, and it puts the results in the variables that you bound with `bind_result`.

You were also referencing values that you weren't listing in the `SELECT` clause.

```
$con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username, status, user_id FROM user WHERE username=? AND  password=? LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($username, $status, $user_id);
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows == 1)  //To check if the row exists
        {
            $stmt->fetch();

            if($status=='d'){
                echo "YOUR account has been DEACTIVATED.";
            }else{
                $_SESSION['Logged'] = 1;
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                echo 'Success!';
                exit();
            }

        }
    else {
        echo "INVALID USERNAME/PASSWORD Combination!";
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
else 
    {   

    }
$con->close();
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: row in...`  now status is not defined

Comment: There's no `$row` in my answer.

Comment: Sorry is my mistake! Problem now is show Success! and not YOUR account has been DEACTIVATED.

Comment: What is the value of `$status`?

Comment: i have in db at status vale d and i want, if value is b account is deactivated else if value is a account is active and login is work

Comment: What `$status` value is being returned by the query?

Comment: now i have status   d  and  should return YOUR account has been DEACTIVATED.

Comment: If `$status` is `d`, then `if ($status == 'd')` should do the right thing. You must have done it wrong. Can you add your new code to your question?

Comment: Can you put `var_dump($username, $status, $user_id);` after `$stmt->fetch();` and post what it shows?

Comment: i put var_dump... and show:
string(9) "djchinezu" string(32) "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e"

Comment: Your code has `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;` Where does `$user_id` come from? I assumed it was from the DB, and you left it out by mistake.

Comment: Make sure you changed your SQL and `bind_result` like I did in my answer.

Comment: at my new code have   $_SESSION['Logged'] = 1;
               
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                echo 'Success!';
               exit();

Comment: Then take `user_id` out of the SQL, and `$user_id` out of `bind_result`.

Comment: What is `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e`? That doesn't look like status, it looks like an encrypted password.

Comment: you say:  put var_dump($username, $status, $user_id); after $stmt->fetch(); and post what it shows

Comment: Did you remove `password` from the `SELECT`?

Comment: i put var_dump... and show: string(9) "djchinezu" string(32) "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e" IT'S USERNAME AND MD5 PASSWORD

Comment: i not removed password from SELECT

Comment: If you didn't remove it from the `SELECT`, then you have to change `bind_result` to match it. Do you understand how it works?

Comment: Each of the columns in `SELECT` has to match up with a variable in `bind_result`, it sets the variable to that column.

Comment: Now is work, i change $username, $password with $password, $username in bind_result